# docker machine create failing on gcp

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, docker-machine

Thank you in advance. I'm finding this very frustrating and have tried all the solutions I have found online.

I am trying to use docker-machine to run docker containers in a vm with google cloud platforms compute engine.

I'm running it from the latest version of OSX. I have followed the guide here: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/gce/

Before starting I have run created a service api and set it and an environmental variable. By going: "API manager" --> "Credentials" --> "Create Credentials" --> "Service Account Key". Saving the api key to my working directory and setting it as an environmental variable (running the command:

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/MYUSERNAME/NAME_OF_CREDENTIALS_FILE`

Then running

`gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
gcloud auth login`

Where PROJECT_ID is my project id.

Finally, the command to create the vm and run docker over the top:

`docker-machine --debug create --driver google --google-project PROJECT_ID vm0001`

The command fails with the output:

`notifying bugsnag: [Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: ssh command error:
command : sudo systemctl -f start docker
err     : exit status 1
output  : Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

I have tried updating my docker-machine to 0.12.2, as per (https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4156) which seems a similar issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Fixed in docker-machine 0.13

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the issue is still not fully resolved in **docker-machine** version **0.12.2**.

The problem before version **0.12.0** was that the systemd configuration for the **docker.service** was using `docker daemon` instead of the new `dockerd` daemon command. This seems to be fixed now.

But for me it is using the configuration `--storeage-driver aufs` which does not work with some ubuntu systems that do not have some [extra packages installed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ee/ubuntu/#extra-packages-for-trusty-1404).

As stated in the AUFS documentation page '[Use the AUFS storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/aufs-driver/)' the `overlay2` storage driver should be used instead.

So you can fix this by editing the service configuration:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-machine.conf
```

It should look something like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver overlay2 --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert /etc/docker/server.pem --tlskey /etc/docker/server-key.pem --label provider=google
Environment=
```

Please note the `--storage-driver overlay2` part.

Then just run these to commands to reload systemd and start docker:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl -f start docker
```

Docker should run now.

**Edit:** another way to set the storage driver is to use the **docker-machine** parameter `--engine-storage-driver`:

```
docker-machine --debug create --driver google --engine-storage-driver overlay2 --google-project PROJECT_ID vm0001
```

Comment: Cool. :) So then it would be great if you would accept my answer ;)